# Using VBA to compare entire excel documents and output a new document, with rollup/totals of duplicates

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have a script (hobbled together from SO), that compares two documents (50 columns x 1600 rows) and creates a new document containing the discrepancies.

Often the same discrepancy will be duplicated many (every) time due to it being an expected conversion.

Is there anyway to refine the output of the script?

Right now it just out puts the First column of worksheetA, plus the related discrepancy fields/cells.

I was sort of envisioning a roll up and total if there are duplicate of the same expected error to make the unexpected errors more visible.

Thank you so much in advance for any advice:

```
    'Look for the [] and replace
    'So [User] = yourusername
    'And [Worksheetname] = yourworksheetname 
    ' etc

    Option Compare Text

    Sub CompareWorkbooks()

    Dim varSheetA As Variant
    Dim varSheetB As Variant
    Dim strRangeToCheck As String
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim iCol As Long

    nlin = 1
    ncol = 1

    'Get the worksheets from the workbooks
    Set wbkA = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\[User]\[Path]\[Workbookname].xlsm") ' or whatever workbook path
    Set varSheetA = wbkA.Worksheets("[WorksheetName]") ' or whatever sheet you need

    Set wbkB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\[User]\[Path]\[Workbookname].xlsm")
    Set varSheetB = wbkB.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' or whatever sheet you need

    Set wbkC = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\[User]\[Path]\[Workbookname].xlsm")

    strRangeToCheck = "A2:BX2000" ' If you know the data will only be in a smaller range, reduce the size of the ranges above.
    Debug.Print Now
    varSheetA = wbkA.Worksheets("[WorksheetName]").Range(strRangeToCheck)
    varSheetB = wbkB.Worksheets("[WorksheetName]").Range(strRangeToCheck) ' or whatever your other sheet is.
    Debug.Print Now

    For iRow = LBound(varSheetA, 1) To UBound(varSheetA, 1)
        For iCol = LBound(varSheetA, 2) To UBound(varSheetA, 2)
            If varSheetA(iRow, iCol) = varSheetB(iRow, iCol) Then
        ' Cells are identical.
        ' Do nothing.
    Else
       ' Cells are different. Let's fill our main template with the information
        Workbooks("New.xlsm").Activate
        Cells(nlin, ncol) = varSheetA(iRow, 1) 'Gives the AID of the related changed field
        Cells(nlin, ncol + 1) = varSheetA(iRow, iCol) 'Gives me the value in workbookA
        Cells(nlin, ncol + 2) = varSheetB(iRow, iCol) 'Gives me the value in workbookB
        nlin = nlin + 1
            End If
        Next
    Next

    End Sub
```

Comment: Does the built-in [**Spreadsheet Compare**](https://support.office.com/article/Compare-two-versions-of-a-workbook-by-using-Spreadsheet-Compare-0E1627FD-CE14-4C33-9AB1-8EA82C6A5A7E) functionality not suffice? (or maybe isn't available to you?)

Comment: Spreadsheet Compare is insufficient, there is far too much noise. 

This script pulls the errors into a fairly succinct format. 

The roughest way I can think to do it is to simply script in a filter and filter out the known mismatches. Id just like a way to roll those up and total them with the script to tidy up the final output if possible. Thanks!